# Как получить Cell из DataGridRow в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Нужно получить значение из первой ячейки из строки DataGrid'а.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать?

Comment: А что у вас отображается в DataGrid? Коллекция каких-то объектов?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я получаю выборку из БД и присоединяю ее к DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Все оказалось достаточно просто.

```
private void DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;

    if (row != null)
    {
        // dg - мой DataGrid
        TextBlock tbl = dg.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
        Data = tbl.Text;
    }
}
```